# Definition of metallic state

Tags: solid-state-physics, metals

What is the physical and chemical definition of a metallic state?
I found this term in various books and, although the idea is intuitively clear to me, I would prefer to have a precise and complete, rigorous definition.

Thanks everyone for your kind attention!

Comment: You may enjoy [the various schematics](https://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/38_laing/tetrahedra.php) that researchers have made to distinguish bonding states, including the metallic state. One definition relies on the average and relative electronegativity, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In many molecules, bonds are covalent. Electrons are localized to the atoms that are bonded.

In a metal, conduction electrons spread out throughout the solid. They don't belong to any particular atom. The positive nuclei attract a sea of electrons.

This means a small electric field can push electrons around. It can set up a current. Electrons carry energy around with them. They make it easy to transport heat. Metals are electric and thermal conductors.

Answer (score 2):

Metals have non-zero density of states at the Fermi energy. This enables electrical conductance (through non-zero phase space for the e-e scattering) and other characteristics of metals (optical properties etc).